# Python/Kivy: how to retrieve a widget from its id

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I developed a simple UI in Python/Kivy. It contains a grid layout of three rows to host three widgets. Two buttons are designed in the kv part and identified by their id:

```
id: 'button_create'
id: button_get_ids
```

whilst the ddi is added to the layout when the create button is pressed, and is identified by:

```
myDdi.id = 'ddi'
```

I would like to retrieve the three widgets in order to print their text (*Button_GetIds_On_Click*). Here is the full code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.dropdownitem.dropdownitem import MDDropDownItem
from kivy.metrics import dp



Builder.load_string(
    """    
<View>:
    MDGridLayout:
        rows: 3
        id: layout
        padding: 100, 50, 100, 50
        spacing: 0, 50
        
        
        MDRaisedButton:
            id: 'button_create'
            text: 'CREATE DDI'
            on_release: root.Button_CreateDDI__On_Click()
            
        MDRaisedButton:
            id: button_get_ids
            disabled: True
            text: 'GET IDS'
            on_release: root.Button_GetIds_On_Click()
        

""")



class View(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(View, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        
    def Button_CreateDDI__On_Click(self):        
        myDdi = MDDropDownItem()
        myDdi.text = 'SELECT POSITION'
        myDdi.id = 'ddi'
                
        myMenu, scratch = self.Create_DropDown_Widget(myDdi, ['POS 1', 'POS 2', 'POS 3'], width=4)
        myDdi.on_release = myMenu.open  
        
        
        self.ids.button_get_ids.disabled = False
        self.ids.layout.add_widget(myDdi)
        
        
    def Button_GetIds_On_Click(self): 
        # GET BUTTON CREATE
        buttCreate = self.ids['button_create'] #key error
        print(buttCreate.text)
        
        # GET BUTTON GET IDS (instead of using self.ids.button_get_ids)
        buttGetIds = self.ids['button_get_ids'] #ok
        print(buttGetIds.text)
        
        # GET DDI
        ddi = self.ids['ddi'] #key error
        print(ddi.text)
            
        
        
    def DDI_Selection_Changed(self):
        toast('SELECTION CHANGED: ' + self.myDdi.current_item)
        
       
    def Create_DropDown_Widget(self, drop_down_item, item_list, width):
        items_collection = [
            {
                "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                "text": item_list[i],
                "height": dp(56),
                "on_release": lambda x = item_list[i]: self.Set_DropDown_Item(drop_down_item, menu, x),
            } for i in range(len(item_list))
        ]
        
        menu = MDDropdownMenu(caller=drop_down_item, items=items_collection, width_mult=width)
        menu.bind()
        #menu.open()
        
        return menu, items_collection

         
    def Set_DropDown_Item(self, drop_down_item, menu, text_item):
        drop_down_item.set_item(text_item)
        menu.dismiss()
        
        
        

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.View = View()


    def build(self):
        self.title = ' DROP DOWN ITEM ADDED DYNAMICALLY'
        return self.View


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

For the first and third widget I get a **key error**. What is the difference of identifying a widget in the kv part between *id: 'widgetId'* and *id: widgetId*? Which is the difference between *id* and *ids*?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define `kv` `ids` by assignment. The code:

```
myDdi.id = 'ddi'
```

will not add an entry into the `ids` dictionary.

from the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.lang.html#ids):

> When the kv file is processed, weakrefs to all the widgets tagged with
> ids are added to the root widget’s ids dictionary

So the `ids` dictionary is filled out when the `kv` file is loaded. You can manually add entries to the `ids`, but the above code will not do that.

If you use a string as an id, as in:

```
id: 'button_create'
```

then the `'` marks are part of the id. This makes it more difficult to use that `id`. For example, to access that `id` in your code requires something like:

```
buttCreate = self.ids["'button_create'"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# %% IMPORTS
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.dropdownitem.dropdownitem import MDDropDownItem
from kivy.metrics import dp



Builder.load_string(
    """    
<View>:
    MDGridLayout:
        rows: 3
        id: layout
        padding: 100, 50, 100, 50
        spacing: 0, 50
        
        
        MDRaisedButton:
            id: button_create
            text: 'CREATE DDI'
            on_release: root.Button_CreateDDI__On_Click()
            
        MDRaisedButton:
            id: button_get_ids
            disabled: True
            text: 'GET IDS'
            on_release: root.Button_GetIds_On_Click()
        

""")



class View(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(View, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        
    def Button_CreateDDI__On_Click(self):        
        myDdi = MDDropDownItem()
        myDdi.text = 'SELECT POSITION'
                
        myMenu, scratch = self.Create_DropDown_Widget(myDdi, ['POS 1', 'POS 2', 'POS 3'], width=4)
        myDdi.on_release = myMenu.open  
        
        
        self.ids.button_get_ids.disabled = False
        self.ids.layout.add_widget(myDdi)
        self.ids['ddi'] = myDdi
        
        
    def Button_GetIds_On_Click(self):                 
        # GET BUTTON CREATE
        buttCreate = self.ids['button_create'] 
        print(buttCreate.text)
        
        # GET BUTTON GET IDS (instead of using self.ids.button_get_ids)
        buttGetIds = self.ids['button_get_ids'] #ok
        print(buttGetIds.text)
        
        # GET DDI
        ddi = self.ids['ddi'] 
        print(ddi.text)
            
        
        
    def DDI_Selection_Changed(self):
        toast('SELECTION CHANGED: ' + self.myDdi.current_item)
        
       
    def Create_DropDown_Widget(self, drop_down_item, item_list, width):
        items_collection = [
            {
                "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                "text": item_list[i],
                "height": dp(56),
                "on_release": lambda x = item_list[i]: self.Set_DropDown_Item(drop_down_item, menu, x),
            } for i in range(len(item_list))
        ]
        
        menu = MDDropdownMenu(caller=drop_down_item, items=items_collection, width_mult=width)
        menu.bind()
        #menu.open()
        
        return menu, items_collection

         
    def Set_DropDown_Item(self, drop_down_item, menu, text_item):
        drop_down_item.set_item(text_item)
        menu.dismiss()
        
        
        

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.View = View()


    def build(self):
        self.title = ' DROP DOWN ITEM ADDED DYNAMICALLY'
        return self.View


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```